# Is there a way to make Android Studio not copy .DS_Store files into APK?

Tags: android, macos, intellij-idea, apk, android-studio

When I build the APK, Android Studio copies these redundant OSX file system files ".DS_Store".
Is there a way to filter them from the APK bundle?

I've tried adding `!.DS_Store` into the Compiler/Resource Patterns fields but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the `.DS_Store` to the `Compiler` > `Excludes` rather than the Resource Patterns field.

Comment: This is only good if you know where the file is located exactly, thing is I don't know where it is as the Finder keeps creating these files while the user navigates...

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal of Android Studio and run the below command to remove all `.DS_STORE` files in the project directory.

```
find . -name ".DS_Store" -print -delete
```