# What do I do with a _DS_Store file in my res folder?

Tags: java, android

/Users/v.cherian259/Downloads/WeatherWear/app/src/main/res/drawable-v24/_DS_Store: Error: The file name must end with .xml or .png

I am using Android Studio to build an app but when I try to build I get this error. I understand that the res folder cannot have anything other than a `.xml` or a `.png` and am confused why the `.DS_Store` is in the folder. Should i delete it or move it?

Answer (score 2):

Of course you should delete it. Is a MacOsx file touched by Finder.
I suggest you to delete recursively all .DS_Store files by terminal:

```
find . -name '.DS_Store' -type f -delete .
```

Answer (score 1):

> In the Apple macOS operating system, .DS_Store is a file that stores custom attributes of its containing folder, such as the position of icons or the choice of a background image.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.DS_Store

macOS autogenerates this file when you view the folder in Finder. You can make Android Studio ignore this file using the instructions in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17782356/5544222